# How can I detect heavy beats in an Audio file?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I want to implement a way to read an audio file, detect sudden volume change form low to high and then store the time when it happened. Can anyone please guide me on how to do that?

A lot of libraries that I have tried give me much higher BPM than I require. I am basically looking for that sudden audio level uptick in a local region.

Comment: Don't know if your problem is solved now but you need to **(1)** Load the audio file into a (buffer) Array **(2)** Create an AudioContext and use it to decode your Array (_ie:_ `audioCtx.decodeAudioData`) which gives back the PCM values into your specified Array. **(3)** Go through the returned PCM Array checking the values (_eg:_ using a For loop).  The values are the amplitudes so look for the numbers that you defined as "heavy beat".

Comment: PS: If you get to point (3) above and show the code you got so far we can try help you further.